# Posting tweet from android app without using Fabric sdk

Tags: android, twitter

In my application I want to post feed in my app also plus on social network, I did that in Facebook, same thing I want to implement for twitter, but without Fabric library, is there any way to post tweet of Logged in twitter user in Twitter app, if no app is installed just open webview like done by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twitter4J](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j), unofficial java library for Twitter API. You can find usage examples, including posting a tweet at library page: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html